# Sending input string field value to action controller

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a field in my view, called `Comments` and every time I include the `<` in before any other character(letters, etc) in the 'input', the action controller is not being called, I think is because is not being able to parse correctly to string,

This is how the property in my class is declared:

```
 [Display(Name = "Comments"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
 public string my_comments { get; set; }
```

It works fine when I enter any word, for example:

`dog`, `ddd@ddd.com`, `>asa?`

But if I try something like:

`<ddd@ddd.com>`, `<p`, `<asa>`, `asasd<f`

the action is not being called and I think is because this is not being able to parse the input to an string...

If I include the `<` character at the end, no problem it pass.., for example:

`ddd<`

I'm using JQuery in my view:

```
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {  
 $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: $("#btnSubmit").data("url"),
                data: $("#formEd").serialize(),              
                success: function (result) {
....
}})
})
```

Html:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-md-2">Comments</div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.my_comments , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.my_comments , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my action controller:

```
[HTTPPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyClass parameter) // where MyClass contains the my_comments property...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an attribute to disable the input validation, but you have to make sure you are certain you want to allow html.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HTTPPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyClass parameter)
```

you can also add the attribute to your variable to allow have html.

```
 [Display(Name = "Comments"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
 [AllowHtml]
 public string my_comments { get; set; }
```

Comment: It worked, I will select your answer as soon as the required minutes to select it goes, one question: why the input validation doesn't allow the `<` character before any other character in this case?

Comment: because it think it might be html or script, and for security reasons does not allow it to be sent in post.